# Riemann-integrability; example of a funciton with certain properties

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a function $$f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{r}$$ that has tree, and only three, discontinuities, is strictly increasing on $[0,0.5]$ and strictly decreasing on $(0.5,1]$, AND is integrable with $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1$.

I've been thinking for quite a while, and always can't make them all be true at the same time.

Comment: Can't you just do three lines with jumps inbetween, then scale it appropriately?

Answer (score -1):

Look for $a, b, c, d$ such that $\frac 1 {32} a + \frac 3 {32} b + \frac 5 {32} c + \frac 7 {32} d = 1$ (this is the integral), $\space a,b>0$ and $c,d<0$ (this is the monotonicity), and then define:

$f(x) = ax, \space x \leq \frac 1 4$

$f(x) = bx, \space \frac 1 4 < x \leq \frac 1 2$

$f(x) = cx, \space \frac 1 2 < x \leq \frac 3 4$

$f(x) = dx, \space \frac 3 4 < x \leq 1$.

One solution could be $a=1, b=16, c=-2, d=-1$, but these constants need not be integers.